# What's the shortcut to search for the next highlighted keyword in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I can click on the "External Libraries" and start typing, then intellij would start searching for what I was typing and highlight them. For example, this is what happens when I search for "google":

[image]

This is great, except that if I want to see the next highlighted item, I have to scroll my mouse wheel down and try to find them. This is slow especially when the list is long. So my question is:

Is there a shortcut to jump to the next highlighted item directly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use ↓ (Key Down) shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, it's so simple, I cannot believe I didn't find it before.